# Refer to UIView by its name in a variable

Tags: iphone, variables, uiview

In my `UIViewController` descendant, I have a set of four "blocks".  Each "block" is a `UIView` four children: two `UILabel`'s, one `UIImageView` and one `UIView`.  All of these are created in interface builder and are connected to the class using `IBOutlet`'s.

In my class, I have corresponding members:

```
IBOutlet UIView      *block1;
IBOutlet UILabel     *title1;
IBOutlet UILabel     *text1;
IBOutlet UIImageView *image1;
IBOutlet UIView      *separator1;

IBOutlet UIView      *block2;
IBOutlet UILabel     *title2;
IBOutlet UILabel     *text2;
IBOutlet UIImageView *image2;
IBOutlet UIView      *separator2;

IBOutlet UIView      *block3;
IBOutlet UILabel     *title3;
IBOutlet UILabel     *text3;
IBOutlet UIImageView *image3;
IBOutlet UIView      *separator3;

IBOutlet UIView      *block4;
IBOutlet UILabel     *title4;
IBOutlet UILabel     *text4;
IBOutlet UIImageView *image4;
IBOutlet UIView      *separator4;
```

I'm getting the data to be set into these UIViews dynamically - and it's always in a set of four, so the initialisation of each block is the same.  Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
Block *block;
UIImage *img;

for(int i=1; i<=4; i++)
{
    block = [response blockNumbered:i];

    [<"title"+i> setText:[block getTitle]];
    [<"text"+i> setText:[block getText]];
    img = [block getImage];
    if(img)
    {
        [<"image"+i> setImage:img];
    }

    [<"separator"+i> setHidden:![block needSeparator]];
}
```

(Note that this is simplified code, in real life, there's a lot more to this initialisation, closer to 200 lines code for each of the four blocks - but exactly the same logic.)  Now, if I could only somehow refer to a view having the name in a string variable!..

Is there any way to achieve this?

P.S. I know I can create all these views in the code as an array of corresponding views, however then I'd have to do the layout in the code as well - and I'd rather do this in IB.  Or is there any way to declare an array of `UIViews`'s as `IBOutlet` and connect each element in the array in IB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`valueForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000471-fileAttributes_ClassMethod_NSPathUtilities):

```
[[self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"title%d", i]] setText:[block getTitle]];
```

Comment: A-ha! Looks like exactly what I'm after.  Let me try it and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

you should think of modifying your logic a bit and make it dependent on tagging. You can tag all subviews like `subview1.tag = 1001;` `subview2.tag = 1002;` later on you can iterate all subviews on tag values.

Comment: Ok, that's definitely an option - along with `[parent viewWithTag:(int)]`